# The complete regular ring in Cohen's structure theorem can be chosen to have dimension equal to the embedding dimension of the starting ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, regular-rings

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian complete local ring. Then by Cohen structure theorem, we have that $R$ is a homomorphic image of a complete regular local ring $(S, \mathfrak n)$ (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0323).

My question is: In Cohen structure Theorem, can we always choose a complete
regular local ring $(S, \mathfrak n)$ such that $\mu(\mathfrak m)=\dim S $ ?

Comment: If $x$ in $n-n^2$ is in the kernel of the map $S \to R$, then consider $S/(x)$ instead of $S$.

Comment: @Youngsu: I'm not sure about the point you're trying to make ...

Comment: The ring $S/(x)$ is complete and regular, and $S/(x) \to R$ is surjective.

Comment: @Youngsu: but why does it mean that we can keep doing it unless we reach $\dim S=\mu(\mathfrak m)$ ?